# Сделать AsyncTask неотменяемым

Tags: android, java

Добрый день! У меня приложение обновляется с сервера в асинхронном запросе. После того как оно получит ответ, этот ответ надо бы распарсить. Так вот эта операция занимает довольно много времени, и визуально приложение подвисает. Поэтому я и парсер сделал наследником от AsyncTask. Всё замечательно и красиво получается. Сперва диалог прогресса с надписью "Загрузка...", а позже с надписью "Сохранение на устройство...". Но есть одно "но". Если нажать "назад", то процесс прервется. И если обновление можно сделать отменяемым, то вот сохранение лучше не делать. Как предотвратить отмену?

Comment: А внутри сервиса, а не активити попробуйте сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается таки выполнялся запрос, просто исчезал диалог (с часиками, мол, загрузка). Достаточно было сделать не отменяемым сам диалог.

Answer (score 0):

Задизаблить кнопку "отмена", когда уже идет стадия сохранения, к примеру. Или в обработчике кнопки "отмена" проверять стадию. Если сохранение, то не давать отменять.